# S_ISDIR returning different value for directory

Tags: c, file, directory

I'm currently trying to do some kind of recursive find where I need to distinguish regular files with directory.
I made a loop to check with S_ISDIR if a given file is a directory but when applied to /home, I don't get the expected result.
I only have a pome directory in /home so expected result would be :

```
/home/.
/home/..
/home/pome
```

but it doesn't detect pome as a directory, S_ISDIR() returns 0 for pome and 1 for . and ..

Code :

```
DIR * dir = opendir("/home");
if(dir==NULL){
    puts("Unknown directory");
    return 1;
}
char path[SIZE_PATH];
memset(path,'\0',sizeof(path));
strcpy(path,"/home");
struct dirent * trucdir;
char filename[SIZE_PATH];
memset(filename,'\0',sizeof(filename));
struct stat * filestat=malloc(sizeof(struct stat));
while((trucdir=readdir(dir))!=NULL){
    memset(filename,'\0',sizeof(filename));
    strcpy(filename,trucdir->d_name);
    stat(filename,filestat);
    if(S_ISDIR(filestat->st_mode)!=0){
        puts(filename);
    }
}
```

Isn't S_ISDIR supposed to return a non-zero value if the file is a directory ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but just because a function expects a pointer doesn't mean you have to allocate it dynamically. In your case with the `struct stat` and the `stat` function, using `struct stat filestat;` and `stat(filename, &filestat);` will work just as well.

Comment: How do you know the `stat()` call worked?

Comment: As for your problem, you forget to concatenate the path passed to `opendir` with the name given by `readdir`. Also, check what `stat` returns, I'll bet it will return `-1` and set `errno` to `ENOENT`. The problem should have been very obvious if you [knew how to debug your program](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check, that your `stat()`-call actually *succeeds*  by checking its return value. In your case, the call to stat is:

```
stat("pome", filestat);
```

but your current working directory (cwd) *is not /home*!

Hence, the call to stat fails with `-1` and errno `ENOENT` and the `IS_DIR`-macro is meaningless. The stat-calls to `.` and `..` of course succeed, since they are present in *all* directories (although other information like inode number etc. doesn't match then)

You have to make sure that you either provide the *full path* in `filename` (i.e. `/home/pome`) or you set the cwd to /home before (with `chdir("/home");`); this should solve your issue!

Comment: Be wary of using `chdir()` -- it can be hard to get back if that's necessary.  Consider the use of `fchdir()` to get back, and open the directory before you use `chdir()` to move away so that you can use `fchdir()` to get back.  if the application exits after processing a single directory, `chdir()` is fine.  If you need to process each of 10 arguments to the program, and some of the arguments are relative, not absolute, pathnames, then you need to worry about getting back to where you started.  But this is commentary on a good answer -- the problem in the question is that `stat()` fails.